# Error importing a static pool workstation

Tags: tivoli-work-scheduler

I'm re-importing my workstations but the static pool workstation: give me back the following error:

*AWSJCS011E An internal error has occurred. The error is the following: "AWKRAE015E A requested resource is unknown. The following error was returned:"AWKRRP018E Unable to find source or target resources for the creation or update of a relationship*

does anyone know what that means?

Answer (score 0):

That message means a problem occurred while looking for a workstation into the system. In your scenario, you should make sure that all the agents beloging to the pool are up and running and correctly linked.
In addition to that, for every agent, you should also check the AgentID matches with the one you can find in the respective JobManager.ini file.

I hope this can help!